# python задание на логику

Tags: python, логика

Задача заключается в разделении строчи "-->><---->><<<-" на стрелки. Должно вывестись:

```
-->>
<---
->>
<<<-
```

а мой код не совсем работает. я не понимаю почему, мой код выводит:

```
-->>
<--
-->>
<<<-
```

```
s = input().split('><')
if len(s) > 1:
    print(s[0] + '>')
    for i in range(1, len(s)-1):
        j = len(s[i]) // 2
        print('<' + s[i][:j])
        print(s[i][j:] + '>')
    print('<' + s[-1])
else:
    print(s[0])
```

Comment: Ну так разделил же на стрелки. Почему должно быть так, а не иначе? Где тут логика, на которую типа задание?

Comment: добавьте в свой вопрос полный текст задания